# where can I get linux-image-4.9.18-040918-generic-dbgsym?

Tags: kernel

I installed ubuntu 16.04, and updated kernel to 4.9.18 (got it from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9.18/)) for bbr.
Now I want use `systemtap` get some tcp stack info, `systemtap` need kernel dbgsym.
I search [here](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/), but got nothing. so where can I get `linux-image-4.9.18-040918-generic-dbgsym`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster  Custom kernels are **on-topic**. Please refer: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5576/295286

Comment: @DavidFoerster The discussion of 'custom kernels' are on topic - we had a discussion on this several months ago - provided they are on Ubuntu (and *actually* Ubuntu) custom kernels are on topic.

Answer (score 1):

The `dbgsym` packages are, for the most part, generated during the packaging build process, as debug symbols that are extra in addition to the standard build process.  That said, the Kernel mainline repository very likely doesn't build those packages, which is why they're not present.

My guess is that you'd have to talk to the kernel team to see if they can start building the `dbgsym` packages; it's entirely possible that entire repository and the kernel source isn't configured to build those packages.

However, given that the [Kernel Team has specifically said "We don't provide any support for these"](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Does_the_kernel_team_support_the_mainline_kernel_builds.3F), my guess is there won't be any `dbgsym` packages any time soon.